# How to add <h2> tag to the product tabs in Prodcut detail page in magento 2

Tags: product, frontend, tabs, magento2.3.4

I have 4 custom tabs on the product detail page.

How to add the  tag to the tab heading.

catalog_product_view.xml

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="magneticBallastTable.tab" template="VENDOR_Dvpage::tabs/content.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Product Versions Comparison</argument>
                    <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">70</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create a catalog_product_view.xml under 'MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/' and add below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">            
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_product_detail" as="custom_product_detail" template="Solwin_AfterTest::tab.phtml" after="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now, Create tab.phtml under 'MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/' and add below script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'], function () {
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery(".switch").each(function() {
                jQuery( this ).html('<h1>'+jQuery( this ).html()+'</h2>')
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```